# can't find my package in data/data folder in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ddms

In Android studio when i open the DDMS throw Android Device Monitor and choose my app and I click on data, than data again I should be seeing my package, there I should find the text file in which I'm writing my data... But the package is not there... So please can someone help...